# How are restrictions introduced to a differential equation addressed when we have found the equation's solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is how I was shown how to solve the following differential equation:

$xy'=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+y  \qquad \rightarrow \qquad y'=\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}+\frac{y}{x} \qquad [1] $

$\\$

let $z=\frac{y}{x}\qquad \rightarrow y=zx \qquad \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=z+x\frac{dz}{dx}=\sqrt{1-z^2}+z $

$\hspace{5.6cm}\rightarrow x\frac{dz}{dx}=\sqrt{1-z^2} $
$\hspace{5.6cm}\rightarrow \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} dz=\int \frac{1}{x}dx \qquad$ provided $z^2\neq1 \hspace{0.7cm}and \hspace{0.6cm}x\neq0$
$\hspace{5.6cm}\rightarrow \arcsin(z)=\ln|x|+C$
$\hspace{5.6cm}\rightarrow \frac{y}{x}=\sin(\ln|Cx|)$

since $z=\pm 1 \hspace{0.5cm}$ was excluded from our workings we consider it as a possible solution and find out that it corresponds to a solution:

$y=\pm x$

I was told that dividing by x at step [1] was fine as the equation would be "rubbish" otherwise. I understand all the workings that follows after [1]; however, my not understanding of [1] I feel like points to a misconception I have of differential equations. In the next few lines I'll write my understanding of step [1] and would appreciate it if you'd correct me anywhere I'm wrong:

I think what my tutor meant when he said, the equation is useless when $x=0$ was when $x=0$ is being considered as a line and not as the coordinate of a point. It's reasonable to say that an expression containing $y'$ is useless when we're dealing with the line $x=0$ (or, as a matter of fact, any line of the form $x=a$).

Granted, that way of thinking about $x=0$ would make the differential equation useless for $x=0$. But, what about $x=0$ as the coordinate of a point? If it's just a point $y'$ no longer needs to be meaningless (as long as the point whose x coordinate is 0 is a point on a continuous curve). So, in other words, $x=0$ referring to a single point should be allowed and possibly correspond to points on the integral curves of the equation.

The solution $y=x$ to the equation suggests that $x=0$ makes sense as a coordinate; but I don't understand why. Why are we including points with x-coordinates $x=0$ in a solution that is dependent on a step at which we divide by x? $x=0$ should completely be excluded from any solutions that include in their derivation the step [1]. So, the solutions should instead be rewritten as:

$y=\pm x \quad$   where $x\neq 0 \quad$  and $ \quad \frac{y}{x}=\sin(\ln|Cx|) \quad$  where $\quad x \neq 0 \quad $   and   $\quad C \neq 0$

This would then give rise to the issue that all points with an x-coordinate $x=0$ are being completely ignored; while, they have as much right to be a part of the solution as any other point does (the fact that they're being excluded is simply because the only method that has yielded solutions uses the step [1]). So, how do we show that the point (0,0) does, in fact, belong to the integral curves $y=\pm x$?

I really hope that I've made at least some sense in the past few lines. I'd greatly appreciate it if you would correct my misconceptions about solving differential equations.

Answer (score 4):

A solution $y$ of the ODE is a function of $x$, so think of it as $y=y(x)$.

Your first step is to divide the ODE by $x$, which implies the condition $x\neq 0$ since it is not valid step if $x=0$. This only means that any solution at $x=0$ must be manually validated in the original equation, since it is necessarily excluded from that point on in your sequence of implications.

It isn't true that $x=0$ gives "rubbish" in the original equation. What is true is that when $x=0$, the original equation becomes $$0=\sqrt{-y^2} + y$$ and this is only meaningful if $y=0$ since the radicand would be negative otherwise.

In other words, it must be the case that $y(0) = 0$ if the solution $y(x)$ is to be defined at $x=0$. You must also determine whether $y'(0)$ exists, and if not, then state that $x=0$ is not a domain point of the solution $y(x)$.

Comment: What if it turns out that $y(0) \neq 0$? do we conclude that none of the solutions to the differential equation contain points at $x=0$? Is it possible to say there may have been additional solutions found for the differential equation had the condition $x \neq 0$ not existed?

Comment: $x=0$ is not in the domain of any solution obtained after the first step. You can try to extend the solution to include that domain point by checking it **in the original equation**, but if $y(0)$ isn’t zero, the right side will be undefined (negative number under the radical), so it must be excluded after all.

Answer (score 4):

At $x=0$ your equation loses the character of being a differential equation, as the coefficient of the only derivative becomes zero. In other words, for it to be an ODE, you have to exclude the line $x=0$ from the domain.

It may accidentally happen that solutions have limits for $x\to 0$ and, even more, that you can join pieces from both sides that give not only a continuous, but even a differentiable function. These compositions however are not solutions of the ODE in the "**o**rdinary" sense, even though they satisfy the implicit differential equation through insertion.